# Class private members set in a group

Tags: c#, private-members

I'm trying to find out how to group a number of private members.
For example:

```
public class Phone
{
  private string model;
  private string manufacturer;
  ...
}
```

In this case, I can call those members by a get method.
what I really want is to group them under 'property; group.
It should be something like

```
Phone phone = new Phone();
string model = phone.Properties.model;
```

Comment: What is it exactly that you're trying to accomplish and why do you think what you've described is the way to do it?

Comment: I try to make it better organized.
This class has a lot of functions/members.
I'm trying to access them more easily.

Answer (score 4):

Use a nested class:

```
public class Phone
{
   public class PropertiesModel
   {
      public string model;
      public string manufacturer;
   }

   public PropertiesModel Properties { get; }

   public Phone()
   {
      Properties = new PropertiesModel();

      Properties.model = "foo";
      Properties.manufacturer = "bar";
   }
}
```

Then, from outside, like in your example:

```
Phone phone = new Phone();
string model = phone.Properties.model;
```

[Check it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Nj1BaZ)

---

About the title of the question, where you mention `private`, you can make them private to the class (by making your `PropertiesModel` type and your `Properties` property `private`), but then your example will only work from within the class itself.

The members of the `PropertiesModel` class (`model, manufacturer`) will still have to be `public`, but the class itself (and the property to access them) can be `private`:

[Check it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sOUfXl) - this will give a compilation error since I'm trying to access `phone.Properties.model`, but it's private

The nested class can also have `private` members, but those won't be accesible even from the "parent" class (only from within the nested class itself)